# Transfer files under multiple folder from sftp to sharepoint document library using logic app

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, sftp, sharepoint-online, azure-logic-apps

I have a scenario how to transfer files from sftp server to sharepoint document library
Example: files in sftp folder are /new/folder1/id1.csv /new/folder2/id2.csv like that every day the files will be uploaded to folders. how to transfer the same structure in sharepoint document library using logic apps..

Answer (score 1):

The workflow for your folder structure would be as follows:

1. [List files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sftpwithssh/#list-files-in-folder) in your SFTP folder "/new".
2. Create a ["For each" loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-loops#foreach-loop) using the output of the list action as a parameter.
3. To make sure you don't treat files as folders (if you can have files in /new, e.g. /new/test.txt), add a [condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-conditional-statement): the `IsFolder` property of the loop item = `true`.
4. Inside the loop (and the condition result `True`) list files again, this time in the subfolder, using the `Path` property of the loop item.
5. Create a new "For each" loop using the output of this list action as a parameter.
6. Optionally, add a condition: the `IsFolder` property of the inner loop item = `false`.
7. [Get content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sftpwithssh/#get-file-content) of the SFTP file, using the `Id` property of the inner loop item.
8. [Create a file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#create-file) on SharePoint using the folder path, file name, and file content retrieved in the previous actions as parameters. If the folder doesn't exist in SharePoint library, it should be created automatically.

This is the most simple scenario, given the folder structure provided in your question. If the folder structure is more complex (subfolders can contain both files and subfolders, which in turn can contain other files and subfolders, and so on) then you'd need to use a recursive algorithm - first the Logic App would need to list files in a single SFTP folder (provided to the Logic App in the [HTTP request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-reqres#add-request-trigger) body), then for each listed file (not subfolder) upload its content to SharePoint, and for each listed subfolder (not file) the Logic App would need to call itself passing the subfolder path in the HTTP request body - this way all subfolders would be processed recursively and all files in them would be transferred to SharePoint.

Please note that each such a workflow is run it would transfer *all* files - it wouldn't check what files are new, what files have been transferred in previous Logic App runs, etc. - that would be a completely different challenge.

Comment: Can you keep screenshots and explain what parameters needed.. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Parker - apologies, that would be too much of a job, I thought you needed help with the process and didn't require the whole Logic App to be created for you from scratch. I tried to be helpful by providing a number of links to Microsoft articles about specific Logic App actions, etc. I suggest you to try creating the Logic App and if you have any specific stumbling block that you need help with you can always raise another question for StackOverflow community.

Comment: ok.. atleast tell me what parameters need to be taken i have made work flow but got stuck with parameters