# I want to transfer multiple files from multiple subfolders sftp to SharePoint Document Library using logic app

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-web-app-service, sftp, azure-logic-apps

The files and folders in SFTP are in format as
folder/new/demo/test/sample.csv ,
folder/new/demo/test/sample1.csv,
folder/new/demo/test1/sample3.csv ,
folder/new/demo/test/practice/sample5.csv, ... and so on,
I want to copy same structure which is in SFTP like folders inside subfolders and files to SharePoint Document Library. I have created a work flow but somehow got stuck here. I am attaching here screenshot of workflow. [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrEgU.png)

Comment: Could you give more details on any errors or odd behaviour that you are facing. It is not very clear what you mean by getting stuck.

Comment: is the workflow is correct if u have any other solution can u please provide. It is not triggering subfolders i want to trigger subfolders as well

Comment: You should invoke the ```Get file metadata``` first, with the dynamic content selected as ```List of files Id```, and then for each file, do the ```Get file content``` action which uses the dynamic content "Id" property of previous step, and then you do the copy the file to destination Sharepoint doc library. see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-ftp#examples) documentation for screens.

Comment: I am very sorry u have given link for FTP but my requirement is SFTP

Comment: This is quite similar to your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69555725/. Please note that the `When a file is added or modified` trigger you are trying to use is fired when a file is added/updated in a *specific* folder - the trigger is not fired if a file is added/updated in a subfolder. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sftpwithssh/#when-a-file-is-added-or-modified